# Get numbers on varchar in sql with Regex?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a sql table in which a column stores strings like:

```
CINTA NYLON CT708 DE 120MM X 1000MTRS
CINTA NYLON 102MM X 1000MTRS
```

I want to extract the numbers before MM and MTRS, respectively.
My result would be:

```
120MM, 1000MTRS
102MM, 1000MTRS
```

Is this possible?

Comment: can you tag the dbms you are using ?

Comment: Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: In Javascript it would be like this: `"CINTA NYLON CT708 DE 120MM X 1000MTRS".match(/(\d*MM)|(\d*MTRS)/gi)`

Comment: Do you know how works [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) operator? [Patindex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) might be useful too.

Comment: Could you give me an example applied to the data attached?

Comment: @JorgeTorres, done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using Regex, and probably very expensive in a large dataset, but it works given the example strings in your question.

```
DECLARE @strings TABLE (string VARCHAR(100));

INSERT  INTO @strings
VALUES  ('CINTA NYLON CT708 DE 120MM X 1000MTRS'),
        ('CINTA NYLON 102MM X 1000MTRS');

SELECT  string,
        REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(string, 0, CHARINDEX('MM', string))), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(string, 0, CHARINDEX('MM', string)))))) AS mm,
        REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(string, 0, CHARINDEX('MTRS', string))), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(string, 0, CHARINDEX('MTRS', string)))))) AS mtrs
FROM    @strings;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(Whatever VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @tmp(Whatever)
VALUES('CINTA NYLON CT708 DE 120MM X 1000MTRS'),
('CINTA NYLON 102MM X 1000MTRS')
--
SELECT SUBSTRING(Whatever,PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]MM%', Whatever), 5) AS Col1, 
            SUBSTRING(Whatever,PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]MTRS%', Whatever), 8) AS Col2
FROM @tmp
```

For further information, please see:
[LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
[SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't have RegExp implemented.
We faced the same problem and fixed it using Master Data Services Functions.
We now have a function like this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [RegexExtract](@input [nvarchar](4000), @pattern [nvarchar](4000), @group [nvarchar](4000), @mask [tinyint])
RETURNS [nvarchar](4000) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [Microsoft.MasterDataServices.DataQuality].[Microsoft.MasterDataServices.DataQuality.SqlClr].[RegexExtract]
GO
```

Follow this link to get more info: https://dyball.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/sql-2008-r2-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

One version using [Numbers](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) table:if your string has an index on it and if it is less than 80 chars,SQL can [accurately](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535534(v=sql.100).aspx) guess stats on this  type of like condition as well

```
declare @id varchar(max)
set @id=' '+'CINTA NYLON 102MM X 1000MTRS'+' '

;With cte
as
(
select 
SUBSTRING(@id,n+1,charindex(' ',@id,n+1)-n-1) as string
from
numbers n
where 
substring(@id,n,1)=' '
and n<len(@id)
)
select * from cte where string like '%mm%' or string like '%mtrs%'.
```